# Splitting an arraylist of strings into multiple substrings and add them into hashmap : JAva | Selenium

Tags: java, selenium, hashmap

I have the following list:

1:  Adult(s) ‎(1 X 9,288)‎

2:  Child(s) ‎(1 X 9,288)‎

3:  Infant(s) ‎(1 X 2,429)‎

4:  Adult(s) ‎(1 X2,712)‎

5:  Child(s) ‎(1 X 2,712)‎

6:  Infant(s) ‎(1 X 146)

I need to extract info from the abve list as follows:

List1 : Adult(s),Child(s).Infant(s)

List 2: 1,1,1,1,1,1

List 3:9,288,9,288,2,429.2,712,2,712,146

Using the below code, but is giving me error:

```
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>getPassengerList(){
        HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>> map = new HashMap<String, HashMap<String,String>>();
        HashMap<String,String> map1 = new HashMap<String,String>();

        //ArrayList<String> passlist = new ArrayList<>();
        int size = paxList.size();
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            //passlist.add(paxList.get(i).getText());
            System.out.println(paxList.get(i).getText());
            String pax = (paxList.get(i).getText().trim()).replaceAll("(", "");
            String[] passType = pax.split(" ");
            System.out.println(passType[0]+" ....... "+passType[1]);
            String[] passCount = passType[1].split("X");
            map1.put(passCount[0],passCount[1]);
            map.put(passType[0],map1);
        }


        for(String name : map.keySet()){
            String key = name.toString();
            String value = map.get(name).toString();
             System.out.println(key + " " + value);  
        }

        return map;

    }
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: have you heard about `split()` method of Class `String` in java ? You can manipulate as per your own concept.. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * 
 * @author jekink
 *
 */
public class Test {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Adult(s) ‎(1 X 9,288)‎");
        list.add("Child(s) ‎(1 X 9,288)‎");
        list.add("Infant(s) ‎(1 X 2,429)‎‎");
        list.add("Adult(s) ‎(1 X2,712)‎‎");
        list.add("Child(s) ‎(1 X 2,712)‎");
        list.add("Infant(s) ‎(1 X 146)‎");

        List<String> list1= new ArrayList();
        List<String> list2= new ArrayList();
        List<String> list3= new ArrayList();
        String first;
        String second;
        String third;

        for(String value:list){       
             second=value.split("X")[0].split("\\(")[2];
             first=value.split("\\)")[0]+")";
             third=value.split("X")[1].trim().split("\\)")[0];
           if(!list1.contains(first)){
               list1.add(first);
           }
            list2.add(second);
            list3.add(third);

        }
        System.out.println("List1 :"+list1);
        System.out.println("List2 :"+list2);
        System.out.println("List3 :"+list3);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Split method can be used to get the resultant strings and then we can add them to the separate lists. Following code worked for me for this issue:

```
    List<String> list1= new ArrayList();
    List<String> list2= new ArrayList();
    List<String> list3= new ArrayList();

    //myList is your original list
    for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){       
        String r=myList.get(i).split("X")[0].split("\\(")[2];//gives you list1 elements
        String m=myList.get(i).split("\\)")[0]+")";//gives you list2 elements   
        String l=myList.get(i).split("X")[1].trim().split("\\)")[0];//gives you list3 elements  
        list1.add(m);
        list2.add(r);
        list3.add(l);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split the string once by space delimiter and then replace any brackets you don't want. Just make sure you check for errors e.g. `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.

```
List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

for (String item : strings) {
    String[] splitItems = item.split(" ");
    list1.add(splitItems[1]);
    list2.add(splitItems[2].replace("(", ""));
    list3.add(splitItems[4].replace(")", ""));
}
```